# Laravel 10 Maatwebsite\Excel как импортировать данные без колонок с заголовками?

Tags: laravel, excel

Дано
Laravel 10
laravel-excel - "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.48",

Много файлов xls, csv ... с разной структурой данных.
Задача - загрузить их во временную таблицу ( JSON ), что бы пользователь выбрал колонки - от куда что грузить.

Проблема:
Не во всех файлах есть заголовки столбцов.
Не знаю как заставить laravel-excel читать файл в виде:
'A' = 'date'
'B' = 'data2'
..
'A' = 'date'
'B' = 'data2'

Или с иными обозначениями, но не привязанные к файлу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;

class YourClassName implements ToModel, WithStartRow
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function startRow(): int
    {
       return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]